# Change command to find any text

Tags: regular-expression, command

I have this line of command to find and remove the string: `text_to_remove(SOME_VALUE)`.

```
find . -type f -name "*php" -exec sed -i 's/text_to_remove(SOME_VALUE)//' {} \+
```

It works fine, but problem is that 'SOME_VALUE' can be any text, is there a way to modify this line to catch any value in 'SOME_VALUE'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `SOME_VALUE` does never contain a closing parenthesis you can use

```
find . -type f -name "*php" -exec sed -i 's/text_to_remove([^)]*)//' {} \+
```

(`[^)]*` means any character which is not `)`, 0 or more times.)